# Heroku Request timeout code H12 when saving

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, spring-data-jpa

I'm running a spring boot application on heroku connected to jawsdb.
Now very often I get this error when the app tries to save something:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
```

When this happen I also get a status code 500 with message:

> Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC
>   Connection

We don't have any idea why this is happening because running the server locally doesn't have that problem with the same data in my local mysql db.

How can we debug this? Do we need to upgrade the heroku server and jawsdb?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've run out of database connections. Thus, the request thread is blocking waiting for a connection from pool, which causes a timeout (the Heroku limit is 30 seconds), and eventually the JDBC error.

Make sure that you're closing connections properly in your app.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I close the connections? I'm using JPA I never open a connection it does it for me?